# What element has good conductivity but is also brittle?

Tags: physical-chemistry, elements, conductivity, mechanical-properties

I'm confused by what element(s) can be identified to have these properties.

The following is text from my 2019-2020 Kaplan MCAT General Chemistry book under the metalloids section

> *Silicon (Si) has a metallic luster but is brittle and a poor conductor*

So onto the MCAT Concept Check 2.2:

> Identify a few elements that  likely possess the following  properties
>
> - Good conductivity but brittle

I flip to the answer key and it says:

> Metalloids exhibit brittleness but good conductivity

So I'm confused how this makes sense because Si was the main example they provided in that passage, and it seems to contrast the two points they make.

So what is an actual example of good conductivity but brittle??

Comment: Graphite, an allotrope of carbon, is a decent conductor and brittle

Comment: Sorry what I meant specifically is what elements on a periodic table, not allotropes, isoforms, different configurations, etc

Comment: What is the cutoff value for "good conductivity"? The [Wikipedia article on metalloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid) gives conductivity of arsenic as 3.9 × 10⁴ S•cm⁻¹ and the conductivity of antimony as 3.1 × 10⁴ S•cm⁻¹. This looks like it might make them qualify as "good conductors".

Comment: There's no contradiction there.  Silicon, in and of itself, is not a good conductor, as the passage says.  Silicon in semiconductors is [doped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_(semiconductor)#Dopant_elements) with a number of elements to introduce "holes" for electrons.

Comment: @user3665690 Different allotropes of elements have different properties including conductivity so it makes no sense to ask for the properties of "an element". Graphite and diamond are not the same but are both carbon.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a "metalloid" is both brittle and a good conductor depends on what you mean by "metalloid", which varies in literature, what is a "good" level of (electrical) conductivity, and even what exactly you mean by "brittle" versus "ductile".  Silicon, for instance, is only a semiconductor, with much less electrical conductivity than metals, when pure.

Wikipedia identifies [beryllium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium) and [magnesium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium) as brittle metals, although the latter can be made ductile with minor alloying.  [Zinc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc) is called "slightly brittle".